# Azure Web App only through Application Gateway and disable direct access

Tags: azure, security, web-applications, azure-application-gateway

How can I make the Azure Web App or web service to only through Application Gateway and disable direct access. So nobody will be able to access through the direct Fully Qualified Domain name such as mysite.azurewebsite.net?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up Azure web app in the ILB [Azure service environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro). Azure ASE is a deployment of Azure App Service into a subnet in an Azure virtual network (VNet). This ILB ASE (Internal ASE) isn't exposed to the Internet. You can follow this [blog](https://sabbour.me/how-to-run-an-app-service-behind-a-waf-enabled-application-gateway/) to run an App Service behind a WAF-enabled Application Gateway.

> This Web App isn't publicly accessible as it is sitting in a subnet
>   inside a Virtual Network and it isn't exposed to the internet. The
>   only way to access the site is through a Web Application Firewall
>   enabled Application Gateway.

Besides, If you just want to restrict public access to your Azure Web Apps with the IPSecurityRestrictions option, you can refer to [this](https://cmatskas.com/restrict-public-access-to-your-azure-web-apps-with-the-ipsecurityrestrictions-object/) to get more references.